# Select last N rows with different column value

Tags: mysql, sql

with a log table to monitor all the users last actions.
The table is pretty simple:

Username - varchar,

Time - datetime,

UserRole - int,

Action - varchar

Now I am trying to find a query that will select for example the last 10 users preformed an action.
I know how to select the last 10 records ordered by the action Time but I can't find a way to select last 10 with different Usernames.

Comment: `select username from log_table where action = 'someaction' order by time desc limit 10`?

Comment: I dont want to get only the username, I want to get all the columns, but only the last 10 with different usernames.

Comment: `select distinct ...`

Comment: This will just remove the duplicates so in case lets say I had two rows with the same username I will get only 9 records and not 10.

Comment: The real problem here is that you did not describe very well what you need. Add example data and expected output to your question (not in a comment). That makes it so much easier. Wouldn't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like :

```
select * from 
(
   select username, max(time) as maxtime 
   from table 
   group by username
) a 
order by a.maxtime desc
limit 10
```

Comment: This also might have duplicate Usernames

Comment: you mean you need the userrole also? you can jsut add that to the group by.

Comment: This doesnt matter if I get the Userrole or not, the thing is that I will have for example two records from the same User, my goal is to get the last 10 users that preformed an action

Comment: This wont return more than one entry for a username. the subquery will first take every user and find their most recent time. this will be one row per user. it then takes this dataset and orders them by that timestamp and returns the top 10

Comment: Ok, I probably didnt read the query right at first, sorry for that. So now let's say I want to filter it to only Users from specific role, just to add the where condition in the subquery?

Comment: I changed it to `limit 10` since this question is tagged MySQL and not MSSQL.